# Bash regex match not matching exactly

Tags: bash

I have a list of lines of text that I am looping through, looking for a specific term provided as a variable.

Let's say in this case, I am looking for my_search_term = "Ubuntu 2018".

My input lines of text look like this:

- "Ubuntu 20.04LTS"
- "Ubuntu 2018"

... so I am looking for something that will skip over the first string but echo and exit when it matches the second string.

```sh
for line in "${list_of_text_lines}"
do
    STR=$line
    SUB=$my_search_term
    if [[ "$STR" =~ .*"$SUB".* ]]; then
        echo $line
        exit
    fi
done
```

... but instead of echoing "Ubuntu 2018", I get "Ubuntu 20.04LTS". Why?

I appreciate any assistance, and thank you in advance!

*Edit 1:* As per @Barmar's suggestion, I removed the quotations around my input field, like so:

```sh
for line in ${list_of_text_lines}
do
    echo ${line}
    STR=$line
    SUB=$my_search_term
    if [[ "$STR" =~ .*"$SUB".* ]]; then
        echo $line
        exit
    fi
done
```

But this loops through the entire text string without matching, and my echo statements output the following:

```
...
"Ubuntu
2018"
"Ubuntu
20.04LTS"
...
```

Comment: `for line in "${list_of_text_lines}"` will treat all the lines as a single item, not loop over each line, because you quoted the variable.

Comment: @Barmar thank you very much! I still appear to be missing something, based on my input strings. I've updated my original question based on this change.

Comment: You need to use an array, otherwise you can't distinguish the spaces between the values and the spaces in the values.

Comment: How are you populating `list_of_text_lines` ?

Comment: In a regex, putting `.*` at the beginning and end is generally not necessary, because the search is not anchored (i.e. it doesn't have to match the entire string, just part of it). BTW, if the "pattern" is actually just a literal string, you can use plain string matching (here you do need wildcards at the beginning and end, but they're just `*`): `[[ "$STR" = *"$SUB"* ]]`

Comment: @anubhava `list_of_text_lines` is a dump of a command line result output. Specificlally, I run `list_of_text_lines = $(VBoxManage list vms)`

@Barmar, thank you for the suggestion, taking a look now

Comment: @Asa A `for` loop is not a good way to break something up by lines; usually a `while IFS= read -r line` loop is better. See [BashFAQ #1: "How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Comment: @Gordon, thank you very much for that link! Using a `while IFS=read -r line` loop worked flawlessly once I injected the input directly into the loop (IE `done <<< "$(VBoxManage list vms)"` in my case.

Thank you for teaching me something about bash!

Comment: The `.*` at the end matches all subsequent characters after $SUB up to the end of the string, the one at the beginning matches everything before $SUB. You basically try to match lines which contain `$SUB` as a substring. No need to use a regex for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without storing command output you can process input and do matching like this:

```
search_term='Ubuntu 2018'

while IFS= read -r line; do
   if [[ $line =~ $search_term ]]; then
      echo "matched: $line"
      exit
   fi
done < <(VBoxManage list vms)
```

PS: Note that your search term is not a regular expression, it is just a fixed string. In that case you can avoid regex and do glob comparison as well like this:

```sh
while IFS= read -r line; do
   if [[ $line == $search_term ]]; then
      echo "matched: $line"
      exit
   fi
done < <(VBoxManage list vms)
```

*Edit:* The exact working code for the OP was:

```sh
while IFS= read -r line; do
        STR=$line
        SUB=$specific_vm_cloned
        if [[ "$STR" = *"$SUB"* ]]; then
            echo $line
            exit
            fi
        fi
    done <<< "$(VBoxManage list vms)"
```

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the accepted answer since @anubhava has done a good job of compiling the above discussion.

The exact working code has been added to Anubhava's comment as an edit.

Comment: Just few small improvements. `STR=$line` is not needed as you can compare with `$line` itself. Moreover `SUB=$specific_vm_cloned` can be kept before `while` loop.

Comment: Thank you! Good efficiency improvements.